# Android Manager SDK will not open. Internal IDE Fatal error. Cannot run program

Tags: java, android, batch-file, fatal-error

A question exactly like this was posted 3 months ago, with no responses or answers. Please Help. I've tried reinstalling Android Studio itself as well and that's a no-go.

This is the error it provides:

```
Cannot run program "C:\Users\Donavan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Donavan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Donavan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.createProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:252)
    at org.jetbrains.android.util.AndroidUtils.executeCommand(AndroidUtils.java:460)
    at org.jetbrains.android.actions.RunAndroidSdkManagerAction$2.run(RunAndroidSdkManagerAction.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Donavan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.startProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:261)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.createProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:248)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and re-install it?

Comment: Does `C:\Users\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat` actually exist?

Comment: Honestly, I have done that three times.  I got it to work somehow after messing around with it, but I'm not exactly sure how I fixed this problem specifically. Now, I have a Gradle Project Sync Failed error at which I can't fix yet. This is the message: Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.   So I'm going to look it up and see if I can find anything. Can you possibly give me some leads? Thank you.